# HIghlight a street in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap

I want to get information about some city streets by their names from OpenStreetMap.
Then I want to create a layer in OpenLayers map that would contain my street highlighted with a specific color (say, red).

Each of the steps to accomplish this might seem to be quite simple, but altogether it's an overwhelming task to understand how all the pieces should fit in. I'm a total newbie in cartography (though an experienced programmer), but for some reason I thought that there should be some tutorials on the web on how to do exactly this. However, I was wrong.

Could anyone please help me with what should I do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

The tiles you're loading from OpenStreetMap are rasters: they're already baked, and there's nothing you can do to restyle them. You'll likely want to use a tool like [Overpass Turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/) to get the data you want from OpenStreetMap and to add them to your map as GeoJSON.

Comment: This is awesome! Just to save people some time, here's a sample query (also be sure to have the zoom level set to the map area you want to query):
`/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“name="Dodge Street"”
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “name="Dodge Street"”
  node["name"="Dodge Street"]({{bbox}});
  way["name"="Dodge Street"]({{bbox}});
  relation["name"="Dodge Street"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;`